# How to get mean by name in R

Tags: r, mean

I get a csv file has data like below:

```
> "value","name"
> 403.375,"C1"
> 409.625,"C1"
> 300.5,"C11"
> 321.125,"C11"
> 740.25,"C2"
> 718.875,"C2"
> 303.25,"Q"
> 323,"Q"
> 146.875,"H1"
> 171.75,"H1"
> 210.875,"H2"
> 234.625,"H2"
> 1640,"CQ1"
> 1742.5,"CQ1"
> 2319.875,"CH1"
> 2449,"CH1"
> 1227.25,"CH2"
> 1157.375,"CH2"
> 781,"CQ1.1"
> 715.125,"CQ1.1"
> 713.125,"CH1.1"
> 670.25,"CH1.1"
```

How can I get the mean of values by names, like this:

```
> "mean","name"
> 406.5,"C1"
> 310.8125,"C11"
> ... ...
```

and get the barplot to show mean labels by name in R?

Comment: try looking at `?tapply`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> data <- read.csv('data.csv')
>
> data
>
> ```
>       value  name
> 1   403.375    C1
> 2   409.625    C1
> 3   300.500   C11
> 4   321.125   C11
> 5   740.250    C2
> 6   718.875    C2
> 7   303.250     Q
> 8   323.000     Q
> 9   146.875    H1
> 10  171.750    H1
> 11  210.875    H2
> 12  234.625    H2
> 13 1640.000   CQ1
> 14 1742.500   CQ1
> 15 2319.875   CH1
> 16 2449.000   CH1
> 17 1227.250   CH2
> 18 1157.375   CH2
> 19  781.000 CQ1.1
> 20  715.125 CQ1.1
> 21  713.125 CH1.1
> 22  670.250 CH1.1
> ```

```
> tapply(data$value, data$name, mean)
       C1       C11        C2       CH1     CH1.1       CH2       CQ1     CQ1.1 
 406.5000  310.8125  729.5625 2384.4375  691.6875 1192.3125 1691.2500  748.0625 
       H1        H2         Q 
 159.3125  222.7500  313.1250
```